# Adding restrictions to my schema

Tags: math-mode

EDIT:

My question is this. How can I add a restriction so that the {CarBook} does not contain more than 900 entries?

This is the minimal complete document Gonzalo:

```
\documentstyle[fuzz]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{schema}{CarBook}
   known: \power NAME \\
   cars: NAME \pfun CARLOCATION \cross CARREG
   \where
   known=\dom cars
 \end{schema}

\end{document}
```

I'm using LaTeX.

[image]

Comment: Which package(s) are you using? Can you please complete your snippet into a minimal *complete* document?

Comment: The command `\documentstyle` has been deprecated for 20 years. Where's it possible to see `fuzz.sty`?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I added an image of the output. It is still very unclear what the question is, though. You're using a very old package that doesn't seem compatible with the current LaTeX, unless in 2.09 emulation mode.

Comment: This package is written for latex2e (that is any latex after 1993!!!) and claims to be compatible with fuzz http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/objectz/oz.dtx

Answer (score 1):

Updating your example to use the standard latex syntax rather than emulate a pre-1993 document,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{oz}
\begin{document}

\begin{schema}{CarBook}
   known: \power NAME \\
   cars: NAME \pfun CARLOCATION \cross CARREG
   \where
   known=\dom cars
 \end{schema}

 The package defines a \verb|\restriction| command $\restriction$ is
 this what you are looking for?

\end{document}
```

The `oz` package has a `\restriction` command but you didn't give any indication of where you want restriction notation adding.

[image]